# Eigenvector of polynomial of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having a hard time trying to prove this.

> Let $T_1: V \rightarrow W$ and $T_2: V \rightarrow W$ be two linear transformations. Show that, if $x$ is an eigenvector of both $T_1$ and $T_2$, then $x$ will be an eigenvector of $aT_1 + bT_2$, where $a,b$ are scalars. How are the eigenvalues related?

So, to start, i associated the two transformations with two matrices $A$ and $B$, and write them in diagonal form:
$A = PDP^{-1}$ and $B = OQO^{-1}$.

Then, $aA + bB = aPDP^{-1} + bOQO^{-1}$. Now, i'm not quite shure where to go.
I'm also questioning this approach because not all matrices can be written in diagonal form (i used this method to prove, in another exercise, that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $a \lambda$ will be an eigenvalue of $aT$, so i also wanna know if there is any better approach). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

if
$
T_1(x)=\lambda_1x
$
and $
T_2(x)=\lambda_2x
$
than
$$
(aT_1+bT_1)(x)=aT_1(x)+bT_2(x)=a\lambda_1 x+b\lambda_2 x= (a\lambda_1 + b\lambda_2)x
$$

Comment: I totally forgot about the basic properties of linear transformations! Thanks!